# Quick way to make weighted random boolean in R

Tags: r, random, boolean, weighted

Ok so I need to make a random boolean based on prior probabilities that I've calculated beforehand. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
    sample(0:1,1,replace=T, c( 0.6, 0.4))
```

This works just fine of course, the problem is I need to do this millions of times (based on different weights each time - 0.6,0.4 simple an example). Of course I have wrapped it in sapply and have parallelized it and it works, but I may need to ramp this up to tens of millions or more and I was wondering is there a quicker way to generate a weighted random boolean than the `sample()` command

Comment: See `?rbinom` for sampling from a binomial distribution

Comment: Aha- didn't know the command! I will try it and do a speed comparsion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sampling from a binomial distribution, and the built-in function to do this is `rbinom()`.

Here is how to create a simple sample:

```
rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob = c( 0.6, 0.4))
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

Timings:

```
> system.time({
+   x <- rbinom(n=2.5e6, size=1, prob = c( 0.6, 0.4))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.17 
> str(x)
 int [1:2500000] 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
```

Comment: Hi again Andrie. Yes that was much faster - took the time to create 2.5 million samples from 270 seconds down to 166 (across 6 cores). Happy with that thanks!

Comment: @user2498193 You're doing something wrong.  On my machine this takes 0.17 seconds on a single core.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, timing reduces to 0.13 seconds

Comment: @Andrie - the proper code is more complex and involves pulling the probabilites from a dataframe:
        `events.pl <- function(e){
            sapply(trim$id, function(id) rbinom(1, 1, trim[id,prob.names[e]] ))
        }`
It cycles through the columns of trim approx 2.5million rows. I'm parallelising each column. Would making it a matrix speed this up ?

@BenBolker - thx I will work that into it

Comment: Ah of course my code produced 6 x 2.5million samples in that time and my clock including various precursor steps

Comment: So the need to lookup probability each iteration is what forces me to use sapply to produce 1 number at a time. This is what slows this down I think ? Is there a way to do something like:
`as.numeric(runif(n) > b)`
where both n and b are vectors it would automatically iterate along ?
where b is vector of probabilities

Comment: the question is morphing considerably (maybe post a new question and link back to this one?), but try: `as.numeric(runif(sum(n))>rep(b,times=n)` (if I understand you correctly)

Comment: Yes agree the question is morphing but that little piece of magic you just posted seems to do the trick! Thank you! Edit: that almost works but not quite I will play with it a bit to see if I can figure it out

Comment: Actually runif doesn't work for my purposes. Sorry I should have noticed this before - `as.numeric(runif(n)>0.6)` for example gives me a random between 0 and 1 and then checks that it is greater than 0.6. This is not quite the same thing as giving me weighted random number. Makes a big difference in my code. However, all is not lost - using the various things I've learned here I believe I can speed up the code considerably. Thanks all for the help

Comment: Replacing ` sapply(trim$id, function(id) rbinom(1, 1, trim[id,prob.names[e]]` with `rbinom(length(trim$id),1 , temp)` took the time down from 136 seconds to 2.9seconds. Wow. THanks! :)